# Why does the iOS toolbar view get added on top of my loading view when I hide and show it again?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

1. I have a normal navigation based iOS app
2. I've got "loading view" which I initiate from my app delegate and use across the app, simply by showing and hiding it.
3. This works fine, but as soon as I hide the bottom toolbar in one of the views in the app and display it again, the toolbar seems now be shown on top of the my generic "loading view"

[image: The first view][image: How it should work][image: The broken version - the toolbar seems to now overlap the loading view]

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please post the hide/show source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically ended up deleting the loading view and recreating it each time.
It now appears at the top of the view hierarchy each time. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you add your bottomBar? Obviously not on the view itself, right? Than it would probably be beneath the overlay.

Also you should use an extra window for the loading overlay. That would solve your issues.